# PPT Animations dropping frame when VBA Timer is run

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an unusual error. I have one slide with 10 trigger animations. Each animation last 2 seconds. The shapes that trigger the animation also runs a delay macro to hide the same shape based on few conditions (hence, can't use a disappear trigger animation as its disappearance is conditional).

```
  lag = 3 
  start = Timer

  While Timer < Start + lag
        DoEvents
  Wend
        If disappear = True then oSh.Visible = msoFalse
```

The entire sequence works when I have only one slide in my presentation. As soon as I add more slides (even if it is just 1 blank slide), the animation becomes abrupt and doesn't look as intended. It looks like I'm seeing 1 frame per second.

I had encountered a similar issue earlier where the animations were compromised when a VBA Timer was run. However, I am unable to figure out why it works perfectly when I have only one slide.

[Here](https://vimeo.com/651979483) is a video showcasing it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean since it's hard to diagnose without seeing more of your code...  but just a shot in the dark here: are you running on the assumption that your timer code will pause code execution? ... because that's kind of the *opposite* of what that code would do. [`doEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) allows all other events in the project to continue running. Or perhaps you have multiple timers running synchronously?  Just a thought.

Comment: I'm using the timer code to delay the disappearance of the shape after I click it. I have only one timer code running. I didn't paste the conditional code as it was lengthy. I have updated it with a simplified version. I was able to pinpoint to  `While Timer < Start + lag` as the root cause of the animation glitch.